# Load banner ad in mainactivity and show it in other activities

Tags: admob

i try to load a banner ad in mainactivity and show it all some other activities, the ad is loaded and appears in mainactivity so well but when i try to show it in other activities i got this problem in my code: W/Ads: #004 The webview is destroyed. Ignoring action.

MainActivity.java

```
    public void showPersonalizedAds() {

    mAdView = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.adView);
    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
            .addTestDevice(AdRequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR)
            .build();
    mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);
    mAdView.setAdListener(new AdListener() {

        @Override
        public void onAdLoaded() {
            mAdView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }

        @Override
        public void onAdFailedToLoad(int error)
        {
            mAdView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }

    });

}
```

DownloadActivity.java

```
  MainActivity.app.showPersonalizedAds();
```

mainacvitiy.xml

```
<com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
    android:id="@+id/adView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    ads:adSize="BANNER"
    android:visibility="gone"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    ads:adUnitId="@string/banner_ad_unit_id">
```

downloadactivity.xml

```
<com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
    android:id="@+id/adView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    ads:adSize="BANNER"
    android:visibility="gone"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    ads:adUnitId="@string/banner_ad_unit_id">
</com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>
</com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>
```